# Issues setting up a N-M relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Using MySQL I'm trying to set up a 1 to many relationship using data that has already been uploaded into the database. For examples sake, lets say I have a list of names in one table and I want connect them to a lists of places they have been. Obviously 1 person can go to many different places, but i'm having an issue getting this set up.

```
        -----Name-----------ID---------
             John Smith     1
             Joe Random     2
             Seth Guy       3
        ------------------------------
```

I have another table that would look like this:

```
        -------city---------ID---------
            New York        1
            Chicago         2 
            Orlando         3
            LA              4
        -------------------------------
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
        --------Name--------City----------
             John Smith    Chicago
             John Smith    Orlando
             John Smith    New York
             Seth Guy      Chicago
             Joe Random    LA
      ------------------------------------
```

I obviously Know that John Smith has been to all 3 locations because the original file I uploaded tells me so, but I want the database to make that connection and place him their accordingly.

Comment: Your relationship is n-m, not 1-n.  One person can go to many places.  One place can be visited by many persons.

Comment: You need another table `visited` with `person_id` and `city_id` as columns. That will allow you to have many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is an N-M relationship, not a 1-N relationship. You need an additional "mapping" table to record the visits:

```
CREATE TABLE visits (
    person_id INT,
    city_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT visits_pk PRIMARY KEY (person_id, city_id)
);
```

Then, you can query all the visits with a couple of joins:

```
SELECT person.name, city.name
FROM   person
JOIN   visits ON person.id = visits.person_id
JOIN   city ON visits.city_id = city.id
```

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake, I will edit the question appropriately. Furthermore, When i implemented your answer, it doesn't display anything, just a blank table.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a new table that holds the relationship.

Your schema would look something like this:

```
create table person (id, name)
create table city (id, name)
create table person_to_city (people_id, city_id)
```

Create a foreign key constraint on people_id and city_id.